# Signing files on Linux with SPC files

Tags: certificate, key, code-signing, pem, code-signing-certificate

I have one .key file from which I generated a .csr file that I used to purchase a GoDaddy code signing certificate. From GoDaddy I received one .spc file.

I exported the spc file to pem with the following command:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in mycert.spc -print_certs -out certs.pem
```

I then opened the certs.pem file and copied the first two certificates to a file called cert-chain.crt and the last one (which is mine) to one called server.crt.

I tried to sign the file like with this command:

```
openssl smime -sign -in a.mobileconfig -out signed_a.mobileconfig -signer cert/server.crt -inkey cert/ios_apn.key -certfile cert/cert-chain.crt -outform der -nodetach
```

But what I got is:

```
unable to load certificate
11911:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-41/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I normally sign the a.mobileconfig file with the provided SPC file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your certificate is in DER format, but openssl is assuming PEM format. You should add `-inform der` to the command:

```
openssl smime -sign -in a.mobileconfig -out signed_a.mobileconfig -signer cert/server.crt -inkey cert/ios_apn.key -certfile cert/cert-chain.crt -inform der -outform der -nodetach
```